# How do I run a subdirectory on a seprate virtual directory on same server

Tags: iis-7.5, web-hosting

I have a site, www.domain.com. I want to set up a blog which runs on a same server but in different virtual directory, and have it available a the domain www.domain.com/blog.

How would I go about doing this? If it were blog.domain.com, then it would be easy, but with www.domain.com/blog I'm not so sure.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7.

I have already been through these tutorial but If some one has better approach please do let me know

[Tutorial1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx?Redirected=true)

[Tutorial2](http://improve.dk/routing-requests-for-a-subdirectory-to-another-server-using-iis-application-request-routing/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to run subdirectory on seprate virtual directory using URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing

For more detail please see here [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add it to the existing site. Something like

```
appcmd add VDIR /app.name:/<existingsite>/blog /path:/blog /physicalPath:/<whereYourBlogIs>
```

NOTE: appcmd is in the %windir%\system32\inetsrv\ directory on my machine.